# User agent error on IE8

Tags: agent, ie8-browser-mode

When I use IE8 it show error on taskbar on one of my ASP.NET pages:

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; InfoPath.3; MS-RTC LM 8; MS-RTC EA 2; .NET4.0E; XF_mmhpset)

How can I resolve this?

Comment: that does not look like a browser or ASP.NET error message. What if you view source, is there a more detailed error description ?